# How to delete selected System Restore Point in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8.1, system-restore

I have occupied 25 gb space of my C: drive for system restore points. Over time, the system automatically created 5 restore points while deleting previous restore points. I want to keep the very 1st restore point and delete the other 4, but the problem is that Windows does not give users the option to remove individual restore points. It only gives the option to delete all the created restore points. Is there any way` to delete specific restore point?

Comment: You should not attempt to delete System Restore points, there is no interface, to delete select restore points.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by only keeping the first restoration point?

Comment: Why don't we wait for the author to response instead of assuming?

Comment: Do you need a kind of "deep freeze" to restore your machine at specific time? What you are asking can work with this programs that create a image of you system that you can reverse to it anytime. I needed this too, but seems that windows restore can't do it

Comment: i want this feature because very 1st and last restore points are important because it contains ipmportant states of system. where as intermideate are useless

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use newer version of [Ccleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner). In this you can delete individual restore points.
Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Use **C:\Windows\System32\vssadmin.exe** it's self documenting: **vssadmin /?**

List your restore points:
**vssadmin list shadows**

In the list note the Shadow Copy ID for the restore point you want to delete: 
Shadow Copy ID: **{aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee}**

Delete the restore point:
**vssadmin delete shadows /shadow={aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee}**

If you only want to delete the oldest one:
**vssadmin delete shadows /for=C: /oldest**

In your case you'd have to **manually delete them by the id in order to leave the oldest intact.** I don't know if vssadmin is available on all versions of Windows but at least on Pro versions.

Warning: also backups made with Windows backup and possibly other programs are created as shadow copies. I don't know what happens if you delete such.

Answer (score 2):

Am i missing something? What the OP wants is indeed possible. The Answer of Kilves76 is really good but just a taste of what you can do, with care and clear thought.

Go [here](https://searchenterprisedesktop.techtarget.com/blog/Windows-Enterprise-Desktop/Win10-Volume-Shadow-Copies-May-Need-Cleanup):

The site says it's for IT professionals, which is why i mentioned "clear thought". But what i found is clear enough to make me go to DOS by running COMMAND.exe as administrator and issue the command

```
 vssadmin /?
```

to get Help, which gives a list of 7 commands. Then similarly get help with each of the commands by adding "/?" after each.

Take notes by copying all the help info into a text file, read, and say, "That's easy enough" and have at it carefully. Or say, "Uhhhh-uhuhh" and get the heck out of there!

(I can almost see an outline of a batch file to make mass deletions easier. But i always think that and usually find implementation a large pain or exercise in futility.)

**EDIT**
A few days ago I said that I may post my notes. Here they are:

```
Words inside < and > represent specific values or names. Specifically:
<vol> represents a specific drive involved in a shadow copy.
<id> represents a system-generated ID for a particular shadow copy.
<id> is found via VSSADMIN LIST SHADOWS and must be in this format:
          {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx} 
Commands are not case-sensitive.
Commands that list info show only partial actual output to save space.

VSSADMIN LIST VOLUMES (shows info about each drive)
        Volume path: C:\
        Volume name: \\?\Volume{e3643db8-f57f-11e0-993f-806e6f6e6963}\

VSSADMIN LIST SHADOWSTORAGE (lists mainly sizes)
         Used Shadow Copy Storage space: 301.656 GB (50%)
         Allocated Shadow Copy Storage space: 301.894 GB (50%)
         Maximum Shadow Copy Storage space: 350.579 GB (58%)

VSSADMIN LIST SHADOWS (where to find IDs of shadow copies to delete )
    Shadow Copy ID: {01d07f39-a55b-4854-88dc-b77fcbebf597}

VSSADMIN DELETE SHADOWS [optional parameters]
    Deletes matching shadow copies for the named volume. 

    There are three usages of this command:
      -To delete ONLY the oldest shadow copy on <vol>, use:
                   VSSADMIN DELETE SHADOWS /FOR=<vol> /OLDEST 
          E.g.:    VSSADMIN DELETE SHADOWS /FOR=C: /OLDEST

      -To delete a specific shadow copy via its ID, use:
                   VSSADMIN DELETE SHADOWS /SHADOW=<id> 
          E.g.:    VSSADMIN DELETE SHADOWS /SHADOW={12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890ab} 

      -To delete ALL shadow copies on ALL accessible volumes, use:    
                   VSSADMIN DELETE SHADOWS /ALL
```

Other commands (read about them and more at the link at the top of this Answer): 
`VSSADMIN LIST PROVIDERS` and `VSSADMIN LIST WRITERS`

Answer (score 1):

To Delete all system restore points but keep the most recent one - do the following:

1. Open **Disk Cleanup** by clicking the Start button. In the search box, type Disk Cleanup, and then, in the list of results, click Disk Cleanup.
2. If prompted, select the drive that you want to clean up, and then click **OK**.
3. In the Disk Cleanup for (drive letter) dialog box, click **Clean up system files**.  Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
4. If prompted, select the drive that you want to clean up, and then click **OK**.
5. Click the **More Options** tab, under **System Restore and Shadow Copies**, click Clean up.
6. In the Disk Cleanup dialog box, click **Delete**.
7. Click **Delete Files**, and then click **OK**.

Comment: but i want to keep the 1st resore point that i created 1st and only want to keep 1st and if possible last resotre point and want to delete intermediate restore points.

Comment: @AkshayPethani `You cannot delete an individual restore point, but you can either delete all restore points or all but the most recent restore point. ` from http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/delete-restore-point#1TC=windows-7

Comment: I have edited my answer. You can only keep the last one or delete all of them. You cannot keep the first one. @AkshayPethani

Comment: So basically what the author actually wants isn't possible, but what is possible, is getting rid of every restoration point then creating a new restoration point after words.  I suppose the understanding the reason the author only wants the first restoration will determine if this answer is helpful.